# Align Bullets in a right aligned paragraph

Tags: alignment

I'm wondering how other professional typesetters would approach this problem. The Brand Standards for this company state that all copy must be in the "Black Box" (BB) and the copy must align to the inside of the black box. So, if the BB is on the right hand side of the page, the copy can run left aligned, but if the BB is on the left hand side of the page, the copy must be right aligned. Not awesome, but workable. However, they also want BULLETS in the copy. I tried running the bullets right aligned, but that doesn't look good, so I've gone back to left aligned for the bullets only. Not sure if this will fly with the client or not so I'm wondering if anyone else has an idea of how to approach this. Please see the screen capture I've included. This is a snap of part of the right hand page of a spread. BB bleeds off left.

I'm not crazy about the left and right justification in the same BB.

[image: left aligned bullets with right aligned copy above]

Comment: What about justifying the text?

Comment: *Must* you use "bullets"? Why not just drop the • entirely? I think ultimately this is a matter of design preference and there's no solid answer for this. To me, that much reverse text is a crime in unto itself. And the fact that the branding dictates that... well....

Comment: I don't think you could do it with the regular Indesign/Iluustrator package. You have to enable RTL which will enable you easily switching the direction. please refer to my answer on how to enable RTL features in your CC account. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/44929/how-do-i-type-arabic-text-in-photoshop-cc-multilanguage/44931#44931

Comment: +1 on justifying. It is right alignment that makes it look bad, but the combination of left and right makes it even worse. If you're afraid of breaking brand standards then align the bullets to the right or get rid of them.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I agree, the brand standards are... questionable. I don't like that much reversed text OR aligned right. I think I will just take the bullets out of the mix altogether and see how it looks justified.

Comment: I believe the black box idea started out to be for the logo and headlines only... and now it's gone too far.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, and OP has acknowledged, the aesthetics of the brand standards aren't great. That said, if you have to follow them, one design solution may be something like this, where you can still right-justify the "bulleted" text, without using bullets. An element like a short vertical rule on the righthand side of each separate section, as a bullet would do. Again, working with tough guidelines, but that's part of the challenge of design, no? :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible tough a bit tricky. Add a extra tab, at the beginning of each bullet, that is right aligned. Then adjust your tabs until it works out.

[image: aligned bullets on right aligned text]

**Image 1** Right aligned text with vertically aligning bullets.

Comment: I actually think this is worse. But as stated in my comment on the question, it's really  a matter of aesthetic preference.

Comment: @Scott yes, I dont personally like it but it is possible, so im answering the question.